# Deleting file beginning with period

Tags: vbscript, delete-file

I'm trying to create a quick script that asks the user for the input file name, then it in the background finds the associated OpenOffice lock file and deletes it. 
(example file names involved: `.~lock.Cleaning Checklists.xls#`
 and `Cleaning Checklist.xls`)

Through my testing of the code and echoing it back to the screen, it seems to work pretty well, except that that it errors out saying it cannot find the file I actually need it to find. I suspect the issue is it can't handle a file beginning with a **period**.

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
'This script will ask for a users input, then delete the lock file

Const DeleteReadOnly = True
strFile = InputBox( "Enter the file name that is locked" )
WScript.Echo "You entered: " & strFile

Set joinedFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
joinedFile = ".~lock." & strFile & ".xls#"
WScript.Echo joinedFile

Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
obj.DeleteFile(".~lock." & strFile & ".xls#"), DeleteReadOnly
```

It also complains about not finding the file if I try to use `joinedFile`:

```
obj.DeleteFile("joinedFile")
```

Comment: `DeleteFile` can handle filenames starting with a dot just fine. You're probably just looking in the wrong directory. Compare the output of `WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory` with the location of the file in question.

Comment: The CurrentDirectory command does report the correct folder where the file is located.
 I'm trying to run this from the same folder as the file I want to delete. (The lock file is typically hidden on a users computer)

Comment: Then `obj.DeleteFile joinedFile` (without double quotes) should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you. This last idea worked, but only after realizing a damn typo in my file name...